# How to retrieve Text Input without Textfield in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, io, barcode-scanner, textinput

When I scan a barcode, the numbers are sent through the device as `String` (I guess).
If I have a `textfield`, and it's selected/focused, the scan automatically fills in the number string.
I don't want to put it on a textField, I want to catch it on a class, process it such that I can update my shop cart.

I tried with KeyboardListener, but it didn't work.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return KeyboardListener(
        focusNode: FocusNode(),
        onKeyEvent: (event) {
          text = event.character.toString();
        },
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Retrieve Text Input'),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: Text(text),
            )));
  }
}
```

I also saw that there exists a class called `TextInput` which is a low-level interface to the system's text input control.

The documentation says

> To start interacting with the system's text input control, call attach to establish a TextInputConnection between the system's text input control and a TextInputClient.

```
EditableTextState client = EditableTextState(); 
TextInputConfiguration configuration = TextInputConfiguration();

final TextInputConnection _textInputConnection =
        TextInput.attach(client, configuration);
```

But I didn't understand how to use this TextInputConnection to retrieve user input because there are no examples on the internet how to use these low-level classes.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did where I want to hide TextField and just listen to text that user enters.
Using Stack widget place other widget over the TextField so that it gets hided under other widget.
On Tap of upper widget using focus of TextField get Focus on TextField.
using FocusNode getFocus function.

You can try is just disable user interaction and apply some styling in TextField.

```
 style: TextStyle(color: Colors.transparent),
 autofocus: true,
 cursorColor: Colors.transparent,
 showCursor: false,
 autocorrect: false,
 enableSuggestions: false,
 maxLines: 1,
 enableInteractiveSelection: false,
 decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
```

Using TextEditController you can get the text entered.

Comment: how did you prevent the keyboard to appear? @ashutosh

Comment: @YvesBoutellier I guess keyboard is needed there and so requirement of TextInput come in picture ! Else normal Text will work .
For TextInput
showCursor: true,
  readOnly: true
keyboardType: TextInputType.none
will help to hide keyboard

Comment: @YvesBoutellier
Also can try by always disable the focus
`TextField(focusNode: AlwaysDisabledFocusNode(),)
class AlwaysDisabledFocusNode extends FocusNode {
  @override
  bool get hasFocus => false;
}`